# Validation fails on f.date_select with values present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a date_select that won't pass validation even though all 3 parameter are loaded with values during form submission. I even tried changing :birth from a datetime to date column type.

```
  <%= f.date_select :birth, :value => @pub.birth, prompt: { day: 'Select birth day', month: 'Select birth month', year: 'Select birth year' }, order: [:day, :month, :year], start_year: 1940, end_year: 1996 %>
```

**model:**

```
        validates :birth, :presence => {:message => "Select your birth date"}
```

**parameters:**

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"LLfZGnEXy1kjNWn0p601ys/dvy7qIyRQ6Wj4rIXS7AU=",
     "pub"=>{"fname"=>"Jake",
     "lname"=>"Mills",
     "address1"=>"342 main",
     "address2"=>"",
     "city"=>"NY",
     "zip"=>"10004",
     "state"=>"NY",
     "birth(3i)"=>"18",
     "birth(2i)"=>"11",
     "birth(1i)"=>"1957",
     "phone"=>"3423426765"},
     "commit"=>"Next →"}
```

Comment: Your code is right.Did it work when you try like this `validates_presence_of :birth, :message => "Select your birth date"`?

Comment: @Pavan, unfortunately the result is the same even with validates_presence_of

Comment: @Jason Have you tried this without the order? Are you sure that Rails is able to create object ```Date``` from given values?

Comment: @TomHert I get the same result even without order. Also switched back to datetime on the column, still no change...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in the create action. I had the following:

```
pub.birth = params[:pub][:birth]
```

and changed it to update_attributes for all params. Would like to know why the first way did not work.